# Create an ios twitter client using oaut

Tags: ios, oauth, twitter

I need to create a twitter client for ios using oauth.I can't use the iphone sdk for twitter.
Some link or tutorial that can help me with ios and oauth?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/ 
it's the first result in Google, so before you ask a question please use Google/Yahoo/Bing. :)

More: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Or here you can find a framework: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone